# Want to group all the IDs, but getting error

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am a little code blind today because i am trying to write this simple query that should select all the books and show their prices. The problem is that prices is stored in the book_sales, and when i use that one it will show all time the books has been sold. Therefor i want to group them by identifiers, so i can only see:

- BookTitle1 - 99,- - BookID923109

But now i see the same one repeating over and over.

- BookTitle1 - 99,- BookID923109
- BookTitle1 - 99,- BookID923109
- BookTitle1 - 99,- BookID923109

Tried to resolve with this query:

```
select title,sales_price,identifiers
from BOOKS
INNER JOIN BOOK_SALES
on BOOKS.book_id = BOOK_SALES.book_id
GROUP BY IDENTIFIERS
```

i get "[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Column 'BOOKS.TITLE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause."

whats wrong fellas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is evident from your error message. Use [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) like so.

```
select title,sales_price,identifiers
from BOOKS
INNER JOIN BOOK_SALES
on BOOKS.book_id = BOOK_SALES.book_id
GROUP BY title,sales_price,identifiers
```

Comment: thanks brother. my brain is off today, good thing its weekend :)

Comment: Happy to help :) BTW sister rather, I am not ur brother LOL :)

Comment: Thanks sis, hey btw i see you are from Chennai. Please contact me if you are interested in job.

Answer (score 1):

change your code to this :

```
select DISTINCT title,sales_price,identifiers
from BOOKS
INNER JOIN BOOK_SALES
on BOOKS.book_id = BOOK_SALES.book_id
GROUP BY IDENTIFIERS, title,sales_price
```

Tell me if it works

Answer (score 1):

The `GROUP BY` statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions to group the result-set by one or more columns.[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

In your query you can just use `DISTINCT` if you are not aggregating data.

```
select DISTINCT title,sales_price,identifiers
from BOOKS
INNER JOIN BOOK_SALES
on BOOKS.book_id = BOOK_SALES.book_id
```